# What is the default resolution of a wallpaper that fits the homescreen exactly in an Android phone?

Tags: android, wallpaper

i am creating a wallpaper app for large and xlarge android devices so what should be my image resolutions that should fit  home screens correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use resolutions in px, but rather dp to adapt to multiple screens. This page will provide you all the information you need : [Screens support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply... But i need to know the dimensions of the images that is image resolutions that i should put in drawable/mdpi and drawable/hdpi folders.

Comment: I can't answer that, since there is no actual link between screen resolution and screen density.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the resolution of the image that can be used as a wallpaper without scaling and the resulting degradation in image quality, its width should be 2 times the screen width with height equal to the screen height.